# How do I retry Celery task until certain time?

Tags: python, django, celery, amqp

I read the [docs on Celery tasks](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html) and can't understand how I do what I need.

I want to start a task, run and retry it every 1 second. After 3 seconds it should stop retrying and return a default value.

Here's a POC code that doesn't work as expected:

```
@task(expires=3, default_retry_delay=1, max_retries=10)
def ttt(args):
    try:
        return slow_work_result(args)
    except SlowWorkFailed:
        pass

    try:
        return ttt.retry(countdown=1)
    except MaxRetriesExceededError:
        return False


ttt.apply_async(args=(1,)).get()
```

The task should expire in 3 seconds, but `MaxRetriesExceededError` should be raised in 10 seconds. But when I run it, it stops because of `MaxRetriesExceededError`.

What am I doing wrong?

Can this try-except construct be more elegant?

Comment: expire doesn't currently transfer to the retried task, there's an issue open about it I believe

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a task decorate to retry task maybe that can solve your problem.

https://gist.github.com/3958777